# State property of Site throwing "NotImplementedException" in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express, web-administration

I am using Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll to check states of my sites by using following code. It works fine with IIS but when it's used in IIS Expresss, then 'State' property throws 'NotImplementedException'.

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager()
foreach (Site site in manager.Sites){
   If (site.State == ObjectState.Started)
   {
        .....
   }
}
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems for IISExpress, property 'State' is not implemented. I tried to use de-compilers to search for implementation of this property but couldn't find it. It seems lot of code is hidden underneath the layers of COM dlls.

So, for now I am not using this property.

Comment: You should accept this answer. As IIS Express is not IIS, many of the MWA API do not apply to it.

Answer (score 2):

The assembly Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll automatically loaded from GAC (even if you reference IIS assembly) is an IIS Express module and not implements property "State"