# Microsoft Web Administration method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-express

I try to get certificates hash from web-site bindings(IIS) using official Microsoft Library Microsoft Web Administration.I stack with one interesting problem.When I try  to complete this trivial operation:

```
foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
{
   binding.CertificateHash;
   binding.CertificateStoreName;
}
```

I get this exception: **Method or operation is not implemented**

[image]
The most strange and curious thing that when I create another test project and did same things everything work's fine.This situation blows my mind!I compared the versions of the library.They are equal.([Version 7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/))

Of course, I try many other solutions and answers:

1)[Got an error while using WorkerProcess.GetRequests method from Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll IIS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181418/got-an-error-while-using-workerprocess-getrequests-method-from-microsoft-web-adm)

2)[State property of Site throwing "NotImplementedException" in IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467389/state-property-of-site-throwing-notimplementedexception-in-iis-express)

3)[The method or operation is not implemented. while stopping IIS website in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349157/the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented-while-stopping-iis-website-in-c-shar)

but nothing had happened.So that way I here.
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Which operating system are you on? And do you query against IIS or IIS Express? And from where did you get the reference? From NuGet?

Comment: I use Windows 10.IIS Express.Of course, I install package from NuGet.As I mentioned I  even compare versions of this library...

Comment: the version number is useless. Please do add a reference from %windir%\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll and try again.

Comment: I just try what you said.Nothing...I still get an exception: Method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: @ArturLavrov Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @CBauer unfortunately, no